# Python class composition confusion

Tags: python

I have the following from http://blog.thedigitalcatonline.com/blog/2014/08/21/python-3-oop-part-4-polymorphism/#.VvwAbjG1XGB

```
class Room:
    def __init__(self, door):
        self.door = door

    def open(self):
        self.door.open()

    def close(self):
        self.door.close()

    def is_open(self):
        return self.door.is_open()

class Door:
    def __init__(self):
        self.status = "closed"

    def open(self):
        self.status = "open"

    def close(self):
        self.status = "closed"

    def is_open(self):
        return self.status == "open"
```

When I do:

```
>>> door = Door()
>>> r= Room(door)
>>> r.door.is_open()
False
```

I thought it should return "closed" not False , why doesn't this work?

Comment: you never called `r.open()` or `r.door.open()`. BTW this is not inheritance but composition.

Comment: because that's what `self.status == "open"` evaluates to, of course, why should it be otherwise?

Answer (score 4):

Everything works fine. This method returns the result of `self.status == "open"`. This door is `"closed"` by default, so the return value is `False`.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work because it's doing exactly what you told it to do. Your code reads:

```
return self.status == "open" # returns True or False
```

rather than

```
return "open" if self.status == "open" else "closed"` # returns 'open' or 'closed'
```

which is the behaviour you're looking for.

Comment: Two things, (i) `return self.status` would be much cleaner, (ii) if this is the desired behavior, then the method should be renamed from `is_open` to `get_status`.

Answer (score 1):

The `==` in `return self.status == 'open'` is Python's equality operator and it returns True or False depending on whether the items that it's comparing are equal or not.

To return 'closed' the return would be `return self.status`.

The name of the method - `is_open` - is a hint that it will return a boolean value - `True` or `False`; naming methods `is_something` or `has_something` is a common convention in programming languages to denote that a boolean will be returned.

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems in your code:

1. This is not about inheritance but about composition: a room HAS a door, but a room is not a door. You **are not creating inheritance**. Please fix your title.
2. Your code returns a boolean, which is appropriate for its method name. Expect a True or False boolean for such method and such comparison, instead of expecting a string, if you copy-wasted the code. Otherwise, rename the method (since it has another intention) and just return plain `self.status`.